# Does there exist a (single line) if statement in AutoHotKey?

Tags: if-statement, autohotkey

```
x:=1
;All of these (silently) fail
IfGreater,x, false, EnvAdd, x, 1
IfEqual,false,%x%, EnvAdd, x, 1
IfEqual,true,x, EnvAdd, x, 1
IfEqual,1,1, EnvAdd, x, 1
If x, EnvAdd, x, 1
If (x), EnvAdd, x, 1
tf:=true
if true, EnvAdd, x, 1
if tf, EnvAdd, x, 1
;If %x%, EnvAdd, x, 1
If 1, EnvAdd, x, 1
If 0, EnvAdd, x, 1
;
;though these succeed
x:=1
IfEqual,true,%x%, EnvAdd, x, 1 ; x is now 2
x:=1
IfEqual,x,%x%, EnvAdd, x, 1 ; x is now 2
```

Is there anyway to effect the statement from the "If/IfEqual/..." page of AutoHotKey Help with the unadorned "if" statement?

"Another command can only appear on the same line as the IF statement if you use the command-name style."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even better one could write:

```
test ? x:=y+1
or
test ? statement
```

And the (pseudo) IF statement approaches intelligibility!

Comment: exceptions: "statement" does not include branches, eg continue

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using ternary operators?

Example:

```
Age := 60
Msgbox % "You " ((Age < 45) ? ("are under 45") : ("are over 45"))
```

[There is a good guide here.](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/27201-vxes-guide-to-the-ternary-operator/) Though it is most useful when doing variable assignment or returning a value.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, so one can simply say

```
x+=x?1:0
```

i used to think AutoHotKey`s sytax was Byzantine. Now i just think it bizarre. Eg with this blatant contradiction of its documentation. But i quess that comes from trying to track Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

No, AutoHotkey doesn't really do much by way of 1-liners (except for remapping of hotkeys).

But you can wrap an if statement in a function or a sub which you can then run on a single line..

```
x = 0
EnvAdd(x)    ;x stays 0
EnvAdd(1)    ;x becomes 2
EnvAdd(x)    ;x becomes 3

;since x is global, EnvAdd will modify x

EnvAdd(whatvalue){
  global x
  msgbox, Hey, a value of %whatvalue%

  if(whatvalue = 1){
     x:= 2
  }else if(whatvalue = 2){
     x:= 3
  }else{
     ;do something
  }
}
```